# Curved navigation bar package of flutter

Tags: flutter

**How to add a gradient color** for my navigation bar?
I use curved navigation bar flutter package to make an animated navbar

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your navigation Bar in a container.

```
 Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [Color(0xFF00D0E1), Color(0xFF00B3FA)],
          begin: Alignment.topRight,
          end: Alignment.topLeft,
          stops: [0.0, 0.8],
          tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
        ),
      ),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        // your Code 
))'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).